# Is it possible to use a domain name to redirect to another?

Tags: seo, domains, google-search, ranking, google-ranking

I have to choose between two names (A and B) for my website:

- A is a cool short name which doesn't mean anything;
- B is a longer composition of two words, the former of which signals the topic of the website by using semantic in a way that is congruent.

Since I prefer the A, but I guess that B is more advisable for Google ranking, I wonder if there is a way to use both, by registering the website with the A domain, and separately registering the B domain and use it to redirect toward A only, once a user clicks on it, directly.

*Example of scenario*

- A user is interested in computers and makes a Google search by typing "computer".
- I hold a website which is focused on computers but is named "`random.com`" because I like this name better.
- I want to be visible by the user and therefore I register the domain "`computer.com`" and I want that when the user googles "computer", and "`computer.com`" possibly is indexed, once he clicks on it the page that opens is "`random.com`".

I wonder if it's possible and by doing so I'd aim to have more possibilities that my website is easily reachable and can gain a better ranking. So ->

*- is it possible to use a domain name to redirect to another, directly, once the user clicks on it?*

Comment: Keep in mind that some sites use short domain names along with a longer domain name. Case in point, yellowpages and yp. You can certainly do this. I am not sure there is value in this unless you intend to brand the shorter more favorite name. That will be more difficult with two domain names, however, I assume it can be done. I would have to think about how for a while. There is nothing to stop you. Just make sure to use the canonical tag to point to the easier to rank domain name first. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as socrates said, in your DNS provider's settings this should be fairly easy to do. Keep in mind that when looking for SEO (search engine optimization) or more search engine traffic to your site you need to look at a lot more than the domain name. Search engines look at content, links, alt text, sites that link to yours, and [many other factors](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) if the final domain name that the redirect arrives at doesn't reflect your content it may hurt you more than it helps. Search engines don't like redirects because sometimes they are used to send people to sites the user didn't intend to go to.

So short answer: look for a domain name that is fairly short but says exactly what you want your site to be about and stick with that as your main domain. You can redirect other domains to it but don't expect that strategy to help SEO much.

Comment: This is the best advice!! Adding a second domain name generally does nothing for a site. I understand choosing between domain names can be harder than originally imagined. We have all been there! But in the end, there is always one better choice.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have already stated, it is technically possible to redirect from domain B (the keyword rich domain name, eg. `computer.com`) to domain A (your short, preferred domain name, eg. `random.com`).

HOWEVER, this is never going to work according to your intended scenario. Assuming domain B (eg. `computer.com`) has no previous history.

> I want to be visible by the user and therefore I register the domain "computer.com" and I want that when the user googles "computer", and "computer.com" possibly is indexed, once he clicks on it the page that opens is "random.com".

If your site uses `random.com` and `computer.com` always *redirects* to this preferred domain, then `computer.com` is never going to be indexed and is never going to appear in the search results.

Comment: w3dk, is right, google follow redirection very well. You should index only destination page, otherwise it look's cloaking .

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Simply go to your webhost's page (or DNS provider page/where you registered the domain) for domain B and set it to redirect to domain A! This should be very simple. The option should be very visible.

Comment: Whilst it's possible to redirect from one domain to the other, this is unlikely to work in the way the OP is describing in the question - to benefit SEO. Your answer focuses purely on the technical aspect of redirecting without taking into account _why_ the OP is wanting to redirect.

Comment: As well, I have to reach in my tool bag and get out the canonical tag hammer and ping that nail tight again. Use canonical tags to point to the preferred domain.